# Simple carousel slider: remove class to clicked element, and add it to next sibling

Tags: javascript, html, slider, carousel, siblings

I'd like to implement (in pure Javascript, not jQuery) a simple slider/carrousel such that each time I click on an image, it hides it, and show the next image.

The following code nearly works, except that when we arrive at the end, it doesn't loop. I thought about using a `if ...` in the case, but it would not be very elegant.

**How to make this carousel loop?**

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("imgslider")).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {  
        element.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("visible");
        element.classList.toggle("visible");
    });
});
```

```css
.imgslider { display: none; }
.visible { display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" class="imgslider visible">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" class="imgslider">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" class="imgslider">
</div>
```

NB: if the `div` `#carousel` contains only one image, nothing should happen when we click on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with `(element.nextElementSibling || element.parentNode.firstElementChild)`: when there is no "next" sibling, then `element.nextElementSibling` is `null`, and `element.parentNode.firstElementChild` gives the first sibling. This allows the carousel to loop at the end:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("imgslider")).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {  
        (element.nextElementSibling || element.parentNode.firstElementChild).classList.toggle("visible");
        element.classList.toggle("visible");
    });
});
```

```css
.imgslider { display: none; }
.visible { display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" class="imgslider visible">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" class="imgslider">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" class="imgslider">
</div>
```